# MVC RouteProvider / URL Mismatch.What am I missing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm sorry for such a basic question but my eyeballs just aren't seeing what I am missing.

I have in my routeprovider:

```
routes.MapRoute("SSOLogin", "SSOlogin/{userId}/{userPwd}/", 
            new { controller = "Users", action = "SSOLogin" }, 
            new { userId = @"\d+", userPwd = @"\d+" }, 
            new[] { "MyController" });
```

I would have expected this url to hit my controller but instead it says page not found.

```
http://localhost:15536/SSOlogin/1/2
```

It's been a few months since working with MVC...apparently my brain flushed all MVC knowledge.

Thanks

Comment: When registering routes, the **order** matters. Make sure your default route is not registered before this.

Comment: Are you sure your controller is UsersController and not UserController?

Comment: @labilbe...very good question as that can easily be typed incorrectly...unfortunately in this case it is correct.

Comment: @Mrchief I am checking ordering and I also found this handy tool.....http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/  now I can go back to having my brain turned off. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry didn't get back to this till this morning. SO...I feel really dumb but since this sucked several hours of my development day I wanted to post in case it helped others. So the ordering was NOT wrong but instead the actual url defined vs url being used.

from OP you'll see I defined as the url:

```
SSOlogin/{userId}/{userPwd}/
```

**NOTICE** the trailing slash after {userPwd}.

Now look at the url I was expecting to work:

```
http://localhost:15536/SSOlogin/1/2
```

No trailing slash so yeah not going to be found. **DUH!!**

So removed the trailing slash from url definition and now it works as expected.

Thanks everyone...it was helpful as your input kept me focused on the route definition.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have any typo (e.g. in the controller name or the namespace), the only problem I can think of is the order of the routes. If you have a defaut route like

```
     routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );
```

you have to put your rule **before** the default one to ensure that the requests are dispatched properly. Otherwise the default rule would apply, leading to the request failing.